# Static keyword usage in Java

Tags: java, static

Can a non static method in java modify a static variable declared locally in a class or is it only a static method can modify a static variable in the class?

Comment: Next time please spend a minimum of 10 seconds on Google first.

Comment: @takendarkk stackoverflow works as my google !

Answer (score -1):

Yes. A static field is shared by all instances of a class and is accessible in instance (non static) methods.

Comment: You shouldn't answer incredible bad questions like this one. This just attracts more bad questions and won't serve the community or the page.